# Access - To know from which country the user is accessing my application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications

In my web application , I need to give access only to the users who are accessing my application from India. I need to block the users from accessing my application when they try to access outside India.(i.e., I willnot allow them to login and will show an error pop-up) Can anyone please tell if this is possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) which checks for requests and

```
String ip = request.getRemoteAddress();
```

Use [hostip](http://www.hostip.info) service api to check for location

For example

```
http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=74.125.236.206
```

This will give you country code `IN`

If you don't get `IN` then from Filter

```
response.sendRedirect("someUrl");
return;
```

otherwise allow request

```
chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
```

---

**See**

- [hostip FAQ](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)

Comment: Note that this approach only detects the country where the user connects to the internet.  Business users accessing the Internet via a VPN that proxies their Internet connection through the head office in another country will be detected as coming from that country, not the country that they are located in.

Comment: Can we somehow change our current location to access a website from some other country?

Comment: @roger you can use web proxies for that

Comment: @JigarJoshi any specific example would help.